# disabling windows ability to respond to ping request

Tags: windows-xp, echo, ping

im writing an application destined to accept icmp echo request, and respond icmp echo reply by its criteria.
problem is, windows xp takes over the received ping, and quickly replies the sender with a response.
i tried disabling this ability through windows firewall and microsoft managment console, it worked but it disabled me from sending ping response through my socket application.
help? thanks

Comment: The ICMP Echo Reply is deep in the TCP/IP protocol stack, and is basically handled automatically by the OS without any interaction with higher-level components (e.g. applications).

So it seems to me the only way you could do this would be to:
 (a) create a system driver that acts as a shim in the IP stack (like a third-party firewall would), or
 (b) use a different port for the communication (I know it's probably not what you wanted)

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to look into implementing a "Layered Service Provide" (LSP):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider

I am not sure though if an LSP can listen in to ICMP (which, as the earlier response says correctly, is really embedded deep inside the IP protocol stack). But if it can, then that should give you another way to solve your problem.

Hope this helps.